# Rspec request spec ActionController::RoutingError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, rspec-rails

I'm trying to rewrite my tests in Rspec and am stuck on trying to make an update to a user.
I'm sure this is a silly thing I'm overlooking, but I've looked everywhere and can't find an answer.

Here's myspec file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController, type: [:request, :controller]  do

before(:each) { host! 'localhost:3000/' }

describe "#update" do

it "doesn't update user" do
  form_params = {
    params: {
    id: 1,
    email: "hello@example",
    name: "hello"
    }
  }
  patch :update, params: form_params


    end
  end
end
```

It seems like the :update portion is wrong but as far as I can see in my routes, there's no other way to call it.

Here's the error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [PATCH] "/update"
```

Here's my routes:

```
       new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                    users#new
      edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)               users#edit
           user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#show
                PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                    users#destroy
```

Here's my old test:

```
  test "should redirect update when not logged in" do
    patch user_path(@user), params: { user: { name: @user.name, email: @user.email } }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end
```

And if you guys possibly know - how do I convert `assert_not flash.empty?` to Rspec?
Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you can't to use multiple types in `type: [:request, :controller]`. If you want to write request specs you have to specify named route (user_path) or url ("/users/:id")

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe UsersController, type: :request  do
  describe "#update" do
    let(:user) { create :user } # or use fixtures here

    # I'm just a bit confused here, why it should not update?
    it "doesn't update user" do
      patch user_path(user), email: "hello@example", name: "hello"
      expect(flash.empty?).to eq false
      expect(response).to redirect_to login_path
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @Vasilisa! This works, sorry the name was unclear - it should read "it "redirects update when user not logged in".

Comment: @MaayanNaveh, happy to help :)